# docker-compose, can't print environment variable in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I want to print environment variable defined in docker-compose file.

Here is my `docker-compose-1.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox
    command: 'echo $DEBUG'
    environment:
      - DEBUG='123456'
```

And, try to print the `DEBUG` environment variable in docker container:

```
☁  environment-variables-in-compose [master] ⚡  docker-compose -f docker-compose-1.yml up
WARNING: The DEBUG variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating network "environmentvariablesincompose_default" with the default driver
Creating environmentvariablesincompose_busybox_1 ... done
Attaching to environmentvariablesincompose_busybox_1
busybox_1  |
environmentvariablesincompose_busybox_1 exited with code 0
```

As you can see, got `WARNING: The DEBUG variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

Am I wrong?

**update 1:**

`docker-compose-1.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox
    command: 'echo $$DEBUG'
    environment:
      DEBUG: 123456
```

I change `command` using double `$` sign, but the result is still not what I want.

```
☁  environment-variables-in-compose [master] ⚡  docker-compose -f docker-compose-1.yml up
Creating network "environmentvariablesincompose_default" with the default driver
Creating environmentvariablesincompose_busybox_1 ... done
Attaching to environmentvariablesincompose_busybox_1
busybox_1  | $DEBUG
environmentvariablesincompose_busybox_1 exited with code 0
```

As you can see, the environment variable is printed as `$DEBUG`, not expected value `123456`

Comment: The answer has been updated by @BMitch and addresses your problem. You will have to replace `command: 'echo $$DEBUG'` with `command: '/bin/sh -c "echo $$DEBUG"'`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compose will expand variables from the environment where you are running compose. To expand the variable inside your container, escape the `$` using `$$`:

```
command: '/bin/sh -c "echo $$DEBUG"'
```

For more details, see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

Edit: I've also added a shell inside the container to expand the variable.

Comment: thanks. I have known the difference between `$` and `$$`

Comment: This prints `$DEBUG` while trying to recreate the problem. There might be an issue with the OP's `yaml` which I don't see... Can you update your answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @tgogos thanks for the error details. I'm mobile so can't test this directly, but adding a shell should resolve what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, adding a new shell does work. Just tested it. Thanks!